# How i can add mail title as custom text not to use mail from

Tags: java, spring-boot

[My expected output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7g2LQ.png)

My expected output image is "https://i.stack.imgur.com/7g2LQ.png" . Inside image if you see the mail from is "**DocuSign Demo System dse_demo@docusign.net**" but if you see inside inbox it is not showing this from data . Instead of that it is showing "**Amit raut via docuSign**".
But in my code it is showing the from (**DocuSign Demo System dse_demo@docusign.net**) data only inside the mail title. So, how i can add (like, "**Amit raut via docuSign**") my own mailbox title for each mail.

My code:-

```
        String to = "rabin.samanta@xxx.com";
        String from = "rabin.samanta@xxx.com";
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp-mail.outlook.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("username", "password");
            }
        });
        String msgBody = "test............";
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from, "NoReply"));
        msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to, "Mr. Recipient"));
        msg.setSubject("Welcome To Java Mail API");
        msg.setText(msgBody);
        msg.setHeader("header_name", "header_value");
        Transport.send(msg);
        System.out.println("Email sent successfully...");
    }
```

Comment: If that is MS Outlook add a tag. Could it be a forwarded message?

Comment: How i can add the tab using java.

Comment: If you see "My expected output image" then you will get to know what i want. Please check the image.

Comment: can anyone please help me to solve this problem.